# Wordpress: Can I create a custom shape overlay on a background image?

Tags: css, wordpress, wpbakery

Is there a way to do a polygon shape overlayed on a background image. A clip-path on the background image deletes the "leftovers", but I want it to be transparent white.

[clip-path but showing transparent "leftovers"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HW6Rb.png)

[Creating a clip path on the column div doesn't allow for edges to go absolute left/top/bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jdxx4.jpg)

Comment: Plz, include your code so far.

Comment: On a side note, `clip-path`support is really low. You might want to go the `<svg>` road.